# Android getting resources process

Tags: android, process, diagram

I would like to know how Android gets its resources like drawables, strings, etc. I know how to do it in program but in my case more of like a diagram. I have searched in the android website but most of are codes. I just want a simple diagram not a complex one.

My simple example would be a user searches in the edittext (flagname) and then displays the corresponding image of flag on imageview. I need this for my school presentation please help me. My approach:

```
[Text] -> [Android Resources] -> [Drawables] -> ????? Corresponding Image Resource Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed explanation on how resources are accessed. Hope this helps you in creating your diagram.

[Accessing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)